# Противоположная eject команда cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, монтирование

Eject все знают, нужна виндовая команда для противоположного действия вставить сд-диск.Неужели такой команды нет, например, гугл не знает :(

Comment: А в чём смысл? Удалённо управлять? Дык, а вы точно уверенны, что там именно нужный вам диск лежит? Лучше уж образы монтировать!

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\>eject D: /l
```

(Where D is your CD-ROM Drive)